# MIME media type application/xml was not found in command line, but work in Eclipse

Tags: java, jersey

I am using Maven, Jersey and Jetty server to build a web service interface.

When I developed and tested the software on Eclipse, everything work fine.  However, when I am trying to deploy the project, and make request to the interface, the server reported that "MIME media type application/xml was not found".

I tried a few days to figure the problem and found that the ServiceFinder (provided by Jersey), can find all MessageBodyWriter on Eclipse, but not in command line.  I also checked that all jersery libs are already in place, and defined inside the META-INF.

Any help is highly appreciated!  Thanks!

JDK: 1.6.0_30
Eclipse: Indigo SR2
Jersey: 1.12
Jetty: 6.1.25

ServiceFinder Code:

```
ServiceFinder.find(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter.class, true).toClassArray();
```

=============== META-INF
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: 
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_30
Class-Path: jersey-servlet-1.12.jar jersey-server-1.12.jar asm-3.1.jar
  jersey-core-1.12.jar

============= In command line (Only ViewableMessageBodyWriter is available)

```
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter CP:co
m.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@28946
139 C:com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter@6a7d46b8
```

============= In eclipse (All jersey provider are avaialbe)

```
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@2fba32e3 C:com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter@60039882
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@6962ed8f C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider@31cc3e7c
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@5dda7d56 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider@1af30c34
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@335ac93d C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider@6695c13b
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@d51de22 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider@4592b04e
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@79ce9102 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider@41fb404
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@689258c7 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider@4c843d2b
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@6002a673 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider@20f1fbb4
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@4dfdf943 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider@44d0d6fd
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@5cf7c5b5 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider@29dafde4
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@ed51dc2 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App@8c5697a
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@4994b329 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text@48e14b1f
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@417e6e7c C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General@6c9ce1cb
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@5387b07b C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App@2acb4dcf
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@71538614 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text@59b02f33
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@2287c52c C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General@9fc1ec5
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@7fa1dd69 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App@7a95626d
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@5bcf59f5 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text@1e69555f
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@a1b12ea C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General@4feaf536
GN MBR:class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider CP:com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory$SingletonComponentProvider@7776c5d4 C:com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider@5d66341b
```

...

============= Full Error Stack ==================

```
23-May-2012 12:05:54 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type
are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter

23-May-2012 12:05:54 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException

SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.test.TestRest, and Java type class com.test.TestRest, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.test.TestRest, and Java type class com.test.TestRest, and MIME media type application
/xml was not found
        ... 21 more
```

============= Start Jetty Server ====
I am using Jetty Web Server, and started the server like this:

```
Context root = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS); 
// Add REST handlers and Singleton providers 
ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("handlerpkg"); 

// Add the Jersey root servlet holder to the root context 
root.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(rc)), "/*");

server.start();
```

Comment: What server are you deploying too? Please post the complete stacktrace of the error you are getting.

Comment: I am using Jetty Web Server, and started the server like this: `Context root = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);
                
        // Add REST handlers and Singleton providers         
        ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("handlerpkg");
        
        // Add the Jersey root servlet holder to the root context
        root.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(rc)), "/*");`

Comment: Ok that complicates things then. It's almost certainly not finding all your Jersey libraries. Are the JAR files bundled in your web apps WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Can you show us WEB-INF/lib as suggested? Seems a bit odd that some providers are picked up and some are not. jersey-core contains MessageBodyWriters you need and that should be discoverable like always, because it contains ServiceFinder class declaration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding jersey-core-1.12.jar explicitly in class path as part of the VM argument.

I was having only one library in -cp, which points to the other libraries using Class-Paths field in MANIFEST.MF file.  Interestingly, using this method, the MessageBodyReaders can be found by the ServiceFinder, but not the MessageBodyWriter.

Now I have two libraries in -cp, which is the jersey-core-1.12.jar and the lib contains the Main class.

Thank you for all your great helps.  stackoverflow is an amazing developer site.